# Why do I need stack and queue?

Tags: data-structures

Well,this question has been asked before and I read about the implementations of stack and queue.But I feel like those things can also be implemented with array or list.For example: LIFO(Last in First Out) can easily be implemented in python by using list.

Then why do we need stack and queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stack` and `Queue` are data-structures. Each of them has certain properties. For example `Stack` is LIFO(last in first out) whereas `Queue` is FIFO(first in first out).

In case of implementation - it is totally upto you how you are implementing those. For example if you are using C++, then you can use array or vector or even linked-list to implement those. Similar case is for python. You can tweak list to your expected behavior(like stack or queue). In a more simplified definition - `Stacks are basically array or list which has the property of LIFO` and `Queues are basically array or list which has the property of FIFO`.

Now why do you need `Stack` or `Queue`? - well suppose if you need a data-structure which has the property of LIFO( or FIFO). What do you do? you can tweak list as per your need. But if in your program needs multiple stacks(or queues), what do you do then? Well you can implement a stack(which underneath uses list), which will give you a generic template, which you can re-use multiple times.